# How organize data in vue component to one structure?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vue-reactivity

Maybe complex question but i want try...

In vue component, (which is modal window for administration slider with few slide types like video, image...) i want have whole modal structure in json object. So i was created `baseTypeStructure` (inputs common for all slide types), `avalibleTypeStructure` (inputs for specific slide type) and `activeTypeStructure` (complete inputs structure after pick some slide type)

But i am in vue (and js) pretty new and i have complications with reactivity...

So if you pick some slide type i bind `activeTypeStructure` from `baseTypeStructure` and specific type from `avalibleTypeStructure`. (by type key)

But i have problems with reactivity... On one side i need reactive behavior because there are input values... on other side there are informations about visibility... and if i change in `activeTypeStructure` visibility to true, that value is changed in `avalibleTypeStructure` if i make clone (without reactivity), every change slide type i do reset all values...

Can anybody help with this? Resolve it this way (as one json format for whole modal). Maybe absolute bad thinking?

```
    data() {
        return {
            detailModalIsOpened: false,
            loading: false,
            action: '',
            title: 'default',
            baseTypeStructure: {
                inputs: {
                    name: {
                        visible: true,
                        value: ''
                    },
                    type: {
                        visible: true,
                        value: '',
                        selected: [],
                        slideTypes: []
                    },
                    duration: {
                        visible: true,
                        value: 5000
                    },
                    image: {
                        inputs: {
                            imageFile: {
                                visible: false,
                                value: ''
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    video: {
                        inputs: {
                            videoFile: {
                                visible: false,
                                value: ''
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            avalibleTypeStructures: {
                none: {},
                image: {
                    // name: 'image',
                    inputs: {
                        imageFile: {
                            visible: true,
                            value: ''
                        }
                    }
                },
                video: {
                    // name: 'video',
                    inputs: {
                        videoFile: {
                            visible: true,
                            value: ''
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            activeTypeStructure: {},
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using `Vue.set` when assigning `activeTypeStructure` and passing a clone? See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Thx that looking interesting i will try this.